# Keyboard toolbar does not appear if view is in a sheet

Tags: swift, swiftui

There's a view to which I'm applying a keyboard-positioned toolbar.
If I display the view on its' own, the toolbar appears.
If the view is inside a sheet (via .sheet modifier), the toolbar does not appear.

How do I fix this? I want the toolbar to appear between the keyboard and the bottom sheet.

I've tried changing what Views the .toolbar modifier is applied to.
I had it on the TextField, but even applying to the VStack which encloses the other views does nothing.

Here is some of the code (simplified):

```swift
struct CharInputModifier: ViewModifier {

    @Binding var char : String

    var textLimt = 1

    func limitText(_ upper : Int) {
        if char.count > upper {
            self.char = String(char.prefix(upper))
        }
    }


    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            .onReceive(Just(char)) {_ in limitText(textLimt)}
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .frame(height: 100)
            .background(Color(.graySecondary).opacity(0.6))
            .cornerRadius(20)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                        .stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 1)
                        .opacity(0.5)
            )
    }
}
```

```swift
struct ManualDeviceCodeInput: View {
    
    enum FieldFocus {
        case fieldOne, fieldTwo, fieldThree, fieldFour, fieldFive
    }

    @FocusState private var fieldFocusState : FieldFocus?
    @State var fieldOne: String = ""
    @State var fieldTwo: String = ""
    @State var fieldThree: String = ""
    @State var fieldFour: String = ""
    @State var fieldFive: String = ""


    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(spacing:15) {
                
                TextField("", text: $fieldOne)
                    .toolbar {
                        fieldFocusState == .fieldOne ? ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {
                            HStack {
                                Button(action: {fieldOne="N"}, label: {
                                    Text("N")
                                        .font(.headline)
                                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                                })
                                Divider()
                                Button(action: {fieldOne="O"}, label: {
                                    Text("O")
                                        .font(.headline)
                                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                                })
                            }
                        } : nil
                    }
                    .modifier(CharInputModifier(char: $fieldOne))
                    .onChange(of:fieldOne){newVal in
                        if (!"NO".contains(newVal)) {
                            fieldOne = ""
                        } else if (newVal.count == 1) {
                            fieldFocusState = .fieldTwo
                        }
                    }
                    .focused($fieldFocusState, equals: .fieldOne)
                
                TextField("", text:  $fieldTwo)
                    .modifier(CharInputModifier(char:$fieldTwo))
                    .onChange(of:fieldTwo){newVal in
                        if (newVal.count == 1) {
                            fieldFocusState = .fieldThree
                        }else {
                            if (newVal.count == 0) {
                                fieldFocusState = .fieldOne
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .focused($fieldFocusState, equals: .fieldTwo)
                
                
                TextField("", text:$fieldThree)
                    .modifier(CharInputModifier(char:$fieldThree))
                    .onChange(of:fieldThree){newVal in
                        if (newVal.count == 1) {
                            fieldFocusState = .fieldFour
                        }else {
                            if (newVal.count == 0) {
                                fieldFocusState = .fieldTwo
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .focused($fieldFocusState, equals: .fieldThree)
                
                
                TextField("", text:$fieldFour)
                    .modifier(CharInputModifier(char:$fieldFour))
                    .onChange(of:fieldFour){newVal in
                        if (newVal.count == 1) {
                            fieldFocusState = .fieldFive
                        }else {
                            if (newVal.count == 0) {
                                fieldFocusState = .fieldThree
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .focused($fieldFocusState, equals: .fieldFour)
                
                TextField("", text:$fieldFive)
                    .modifier(CharInputModifier(char:$fieldFive))
                    .onChange(of:fieldFive){newVal in
                        if (newVal.count == 0) {
                            fieldFocusState = .fieldFour
                        }
                    }
                    .focused($fieldFocusState, equals: .fieldFive)
                
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then this goes on a sheet. If I just display ManualDeviceCodeInput as a standalone view, it works fine. In a sheet, nothing appears.

The idea here is that devices are prefixed with a character (N/O), and I'm trying to present the number pad with the two character options as items on the toolbar.

Comment: It will help if you include enough sample code to demonstrate your issue. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @ScottM sorry, forgot about that. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 0):

On my simulator running iOS 17.2, that toolbar displays when your form view is either the main view or in a sheet. It's possible that it's an issue present in earlier versions.

For the best chance of working, I'd recommend tweaking your toolbar code a little. Rather than placing your conditional around the `ToolbarItem`, move the condition to inside the `ToolbarItem`. For example:

```swift
.toolbar {
  ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {
    if fieldFocusState == .fieldOne {
      HStack {
        // etc
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my experience, the `@ToolbarContentBuilder` block you define with `.toolbar { ... }` isn't always as responsive to state changes as the views in its `ToolbarItem` subgroups, so this is a way to improve the chances that the change in `fieldFocusState` will trigger a redraw. If a `ToolbarItem` resolves to an empty view (e.g., when the `if` statement is false and there's no `else` replacement) the item doesn't take up any space – so the overall visual impact should be the same.